# override SemanticException [Error 10001]

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-configuration

I want to alter 1000s table in hive database, but some of their tables exits some doesn't. As I execute that .sql file, as soon as it found table not present, it exits from hive. so help me out to override or skip those queries whose table is not present in hive

Comment: mind sharing what "that .sql file" looks like?

Comment: I can't share that .sql file, but it all consists of alter statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration parameter:

```
set hive.cli.errors.ignore=true;
```

After setting it to 'true', all commands in the script are executed, no matter how many failed.

See here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1847

Comment: But can you tell me how I can write it's output in a file, so I can know which are the tables that doesn't exists?

Comment: @user9185088 Redirect STDERR and STDOUT output into the log file: `hive -f "your_script.hql" 2>&1 | tee "log_dir/your_script".log`