# Entire hive file (hive -f) execution fails on one bad query

Tags: hive

Entire hive file `hive -f` command stops execution if there is one wrong query

For example I have below `file.hql`

```
DESC FORMATTED foo.wrong_bar;
DESC FORMATTED foo.bar;
```

While executing below (hive batch) command

```
hive -f file.hql
```

If `foo.wrong_bar` table doesn't exist, the hive command will fail and will not execute second query too.

How to make execution continue to next query if first query execution fails.

I have 1000 queries to execute and some queries might fail but I don't want to stop execution for failed queries. How can I achieve it in batch mode?

Comment: Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48145951/2700344